# Controlled pitch or frequency shifting in Unity3d

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, audio

TL;DR - I'm looking for a plugin or technique to pitch shift audio assets precisely.

I'm working on a unity3d project to create a [binaural](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beat_(acoustics)#Binaural_beats) VR music visualizer ([why I'm trying](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4428073/)). I've created a basic visualizer and the music player components pretty easily with tutorials online but I'd like to find an easy way of frequency shifting audio tracks. This is similar to pitch-shifting, which unity supports via the [Audio Pitch Shifter Effect](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-AudioPitchShifterEffect.html) but it's expressed as a multiplier rather then a unit of measure and effects playback speed. However, I need to pitch-shift the audio while maintaining playback rate as the normal audio plays in one ear, and the effected audio plays in the other.

The goal being that I can use a standard slider to decide the frequency of the binaural wave, and relate it to the left and right audio output, and with the VR solution, I can provide similar bi-visual effects at the appropriate frequency in each eye for a more intense effect.

Answer (score 0):

I think I might have found my own solution buried in plugins - but it's much more specific then I would have thought: https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/66518

Though I would like to hear anyone else's approach to advanced audio effects like this.

Comment: Does the Audio Pitch Shifter really also increase/decrease rate of playback? That seems like an incredibly deceptive naming of a feature if it does. It's not a shifter, at all. It's a rate changer.